# Finding the location obtained by GPS_Provider and Network_Provider at the same time stamp

Tags: android, locationmanager, location-based-service

I have been trying to find the location obtained by `GPS_Provider` and `Network_Provider` for every 5 minutes and at the same time stamp for the two  values obtained at any specific time.

I tried using the following location strategy given

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
      makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
  };

// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 300000, 0, locationListener)
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,300000, 0, locationListener)
```

But here the Location Manager  will call the `onLocationChanged()` method of the listener if the time since last location update is greater than the `notificationInterval`.

This brings me some time stamp difference between values generated by `GPS_Provider` and `Network_Provider` after every 5 minutes.Is there any way such that I can find the location that `GPS_Provider` and `Network_Provider` generate at a same time stamp.

Example:

Now: `GPS_Provider`(lat,long) at 09:35:12 , `Network_Provider`(lat,long) at 09:35:14

I need: `GPS_Provider`(lat,long) at 09:35:12 , `Network_Provider`(lat,long) at 09:35:12

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.
The location api doesn't work in a synchronous way, meaning you have no guarantee when exactly you'll get the update. the time frames which you supply state the maximum interval between updates.
Having said that, you could start the updates with lower interval (such as 50ms) and get a bunch of updates, sort them by the second of the timestamp and get the ones which have the same value.

### Update

You can use the getLastKnownLocation method to get the last location known by the provider, check the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)).

Comment: I have done some research but no luck too. Just wondering if there is any other class in android api where we can manually know the current location irrespective of there is a change in location.